# Корректное использование HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, httpclient

Вкратце опишу логику (клиент стучиться сначала к моему сервису, я отправляю запрос в БД, и достаю данные клиента. Затем я отправляю телефон клиента на сторонний апи, и он мне возвращает данные в формате Json. Если такой  клиент у них есть, сверяю данные по определённым полям. Если они сходятся, то возвращаю Id из моей БД, если они отличаются, обновляю данные в моей БД новыми данными из ответа стороннего API, и снова возвращаю Id записи).
Вся модель асинхронная. Метод  в Webapi-controller вызывает **ClassLibrary**. В ClassLibrary организована логика, которая стучится на сторонний API (Get, Put, Post - queries). Работаю с **HttpClient()**. Из статьи [YOU'RE USING HTTPCLIENT WRONG AND IT IS DESTABILIZING YOUR SOFTWARE](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) вынес для себя полезное, что нужно ипользовать **static HttpClient()**, т.к. подключения могут оставаться открытыми.
Когда приходит ответ от сервера, я использую **ReadAsStreamAsync()** вместо **ReadAsStringAsync()**, и далее **JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stream)**. Вот пример моего кода (привожу описание только одного запроса, логика остальных методов построена тем же способом): `

```
public class SomeClient
{
    private static ILogger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    public static HttpClient _httpClient {get;set;}
    public SomeClient()
        {
            _httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiUrl"])
            };
    }
    public async Task<T> Binding<T>(string _urlApiMethod) where T : class
        {
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpRequestMessage _request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, _urlApiMethod);
            using (var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(_request))
            {
                var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return DeserializeJsonFromStream<T>(stream);
                }
                var content = await StreamToStringAsync(stream);
                var exception = new ApiException
                {
                    StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode,
                    Content = content
                };
                _logger.Error($"UrlApiMethod {_urlApiMethod} has error: {exception.Content} | status code: {exception.StatusCode}");
                throw exception;
            }
        }`
```

На сервис будут обращаться порядка 1000 пользователей в минуту. Проводил тесты только ссылался на фейковый Api (JsonPlaceholder). вроде всё работает, постарался оптимизировать как мог. М.б.  я что то упускаю, в данном ключе ?

Comment: В чем вопрос? И о каком сервисе вы пишете?

Comment: Извиняюсь, видимо до конца не уточнил. При большей нагрузке на сервер,стоит ли как то оптимизировать запросы ? Сервис я сам создаю для интеграции между клиентом и компаниями.

Comment: Зависит от того, что вы подразумеваете под большой нагрузкой. Если вы в бд ходите, то подумайте о кеше, если у вас что то с алгоритмами связано, то надо думать об оптимизации алгоритмов. Если у вас ресурсов много доступных, я бы думал о масштабировании сервиса (например, о балансиррвщике и нескольких инстансах веб сервиса), если бд узкое место - то рассмотреть возможность масштабирования бд, то есть тут как бы полно вариантов, сложно сказать что в вам надо в вашем конкретном случае, но оптимизация httpclient - вы бы об этом думал только если все другие опции кончились

Comment: К тому же не очень ясно, как httpclient поведет себя при многопоточной нагрузке. Может оптимизации из той статьи имеют смысл, а может и нет, это надо проверять и замерять конкретно на вашем проекте.

Comment: Про это написано в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) кстати `HttpClient предназначено для однократного создания и повторного использования в течение всего жизненного цикла приложения. При создании экземпляра класса HttpClient для каждого запроса будет исчерпано количество сокетов, доступных при высоких нагрузках. Это приведет к ошибкам SocketException.`.

Comment: Почитал документацию, но там приводится пример именно со static HttpClient. Всё же использовать static у моём сервисе приведёт к ошибке, данные не будут записаны верно, несколько клиентов могут постучаться на контроллер, и к  этому времени static HttpClient уже вернёт ответ от API, один и тот же респонс будет для нескольких клиентов, поэтому буду использовать только создание  var client =  new HttpClient().

Comment: Один объект - не обязательно `static`. Я бы создал некий класс-обертку, который бы имел в себе объект клиента и необходимые методы отправки. Данный класс был бы "одиночкой" (singleton), который бы жил все время работы приложения (или неким сервисом для IoC с пометкой "singleton"). Все, дальше через него я уже делал все свои запросы. Но тут увы, я не проверял, лишь говорю, как бы поступил я. P.S. Если вы хотите уведомить человека о своем сообщение, то напишите его ник через @, ибо я совершенно случайно зашел сюда и увидел активность.